# Find and group together adjacent characters in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to group together adjacent (vertically and horizontally) characters in an array, in this case all the adjacent "*" belong to one group, see below. And then I want to be able to count how many groups of "*" there are, in this case the answer is 3.

```
var x = ["...***....",
         "..*****...",
         "...***....",
         "........*.",
         ".......***",
         "..*.....*.",
         ".***......"];
```

The code:

```
function compareRows(){
    var totalGroups = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {        
        var array = x[i];

        for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            var row = array[j];

            for (k = 0; k < row.length; k++) {
                var char1 = row[k];
                var nextRow = j+1;
                var char2 = row[nextRow];

                if(char1== "*"){
                    if(char1 != char2) {
                            totalGroups+=1;
                    }
                } else {
                    //console.log("Keep searching..");
                }
            }
        }       
        } console.log(totalGroups); 
    }
    compareRows();
```

So basically for each row I'm searching for the character "*" and when it's found, if the character at the same index on the row below isn't a "*", then one group is found. However, at the moment totalGroups is 20, the total amout of "*" found in the whole array. I feel a bit stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Map it out as a multidimensional array like a table. `arr[i][j]`

Comment: beware of groups like `*.*` `***` `*.*` ; i.e. concave shapes

Comment: Hmm.. I made a multidimensional table of x, still doesn't work though..

Comment: can you tell us how the output looks like and how you achieved it in detail

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to walk the grid at any point you find an asterisk and keep track of cells you have already visited. You can do so with a `visited` array to avoid walking the same cell twice and a recursive walk function. Here's what I was able to come up with:

```js
const grid = [
  "...***....",
  "..*****...",
  "...***....",
  "........*.",
  ".......***",
  "..*.....*.",
  ".***......"
];

function getGroups(grid) {
  // split the grid into a 2d array of objects (cells)
  const cellGrid = grid.map((s, y) => s.split('').map((value, x) => ({value, x, y})));
  const height = cellGrid.length;
  const width = cellGrid[0].length;
  const visited = []; // keep track of visited cells
  const groups = [];
  let currentGroup = [];
  
  // walk each cell left-to-right top-to-bottom
  for(let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      walkFromCell(x, y, true);
    }
  }
  
  return groups;
  
  function walkFromCell(x, y, groupStart) {
    const cell = getCell(x, y);
    // ignore visited and non-group cells
    if(!cell || cell.value !== '*' || visited.includes(cell)) return;

    currentGroup.push(cell);
    visited.push(cell);

    walkFromCell(x + 1, y, false);
    walkFromCell(x - 1, y, false);
    walkFromCell(x, y + 1, false);

    // groupStart is only true for the first cell in a group
    if(groupStart) {
      groups.push(currentGroup);
      currentGroup = [];
    }
  }
  
  function getCell(x, y) {
    return cellGrid[y] ? cellGrid[y][x] : null;
  }
}

const groups = getGroups(grid);
const groupCount = groups.length;
console.log(`Count = ${groupCount}`);
console.log('Groups =', groups);
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I wanted my grid to contain several grids, should i loop through the grids, and for each grid call getGroups(grid); ?

Comment: As long as each grid is in the same format of the one in your post (array of strings of equal length), it should work.

Comment: And if they would be of different sizes? i just change const and let to var?